# Angular - Modificar timestamps de un objeto

Tags: angular

En angular tengo una llamada a una API que me devuelve una respuesta. Esa respuesta es un objeto con fechaInicio y fechaFin. Necesito agregar a esas fechas una zona horaria.

El codigo es:

```
      .subscribe(
            response => {

              //AQUI INTENTO AGREGAR TIMEZONE A LOS TIMESTAMPS
               response["body"].forEach((element:any) => {
                   element.fechaInicio=moment_timezone(  element.fechaInicio).tz(localStorage.getItem("timezone")).valueOf();
                   element.fechaFin=moment_timezone(  element.fechaFin).tz(localStorage.getItem("timezone")).valueOf();
              });

              this.alerts = response["body"];
              this.dtTrigger.next();  
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
```

Como podemos ver intento agregar una zona horaria usando `moment_timezone`, pero no funciona.

La preguna es: ¿Como puedo modificar el objeto que me llega agregando a los timestamp una zona horaria?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Respuesta del servicio

```
Array(5)
0: {id: 170, fechaInicio: 1541062800000, fechaFin: NaN, alarma: 1799, idDatameter: 3, …}
1: {id: 179, fechaInicio: 1567417140, fechaFin: 1567417140, alarma: 1797, idDatameter: 61, …}
2: {id: 180, fechaInicio: 1567417140, fechaFin: 1567498260, alarma: 1797, idDatameter: 61, …}
3: {id: 181, fechaInicio: 1567498260, fechaFin: 1567510560, alarma: 1797, idDatameter: 61, …}
4: {id: 183, fechaInicio: 1567510560, fechaFin: NaN, alarma: 1797, idDatameter: 61, …}
```

Comment: Deberías  [edit] tu pregunta y arreglar un poco el código, usando quizá comentarios (`//`) porque eso no es código JS o TS válido y no me deja muy claro qué te llega del API y qué quieres obtener

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta, a ver si ahora se entiende.

Comment: Cuando dices que no funciona, ¿a qué te refieres? ¿da un error?. ¿Qué tiene `response.body`?

Comment: Que cuando pinto  response["body"]; las fechas no tienen la zona horaria.

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que tenes el Date en milisegundos, lo que necesitas es usar formatDate() de @angular/common. Pasandole como parámetro el date en milisegundos te va a devolver un string que represente el Date en el formato locale que estes usando.
Podes leer la doc. desde [acá](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)